# Quotient group of $D(2,3,7)$ under the Klein Quartic

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quotient-spaces, isometry, quotient-group

The [Klein Quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic) is a quotient space of the hyperbolic plane. Let $k$ be its quotient map. Given two isometries $f,g$ of the hyperbolic plane, we say that $f \cong g$ iff $k \circ f = k \circ g$.

The [Von Dyck group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#Von_Dyck_groups) $D(2,3,7)$ is a group of isometries of the hyperbolic plane. It can be presented by $\langle r,m|r^7 = m^2 = (rm)^3 = 1 \rangle$.

My question is, what is $D(2,3,7)/\cong$ (both the group, and the quotient map)?

Note: The Klein Quartic can be tiled by $(2,3,7)$ triangles, so the group elements will correspond to those (half of those) triangles (and in particular will be a finite group).

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article [Klein quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic) answer your question? The group is the simple group of order 168.

Comment: @Somos I am asking about a certain isometries only (those in the Von Dyck group), not all of them. If all of them are in the Von Dyck group, that would be valid answer though.

Comment: @Somos also, I would want the quotient map as well.

Answer (score 1):

The group is isomorphic to $GL(3,2)$. The quotient map $k$ is generated by

$$k(r) = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$k(m) = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

These matrices where found by a computer program looking for matrices that satisfied the Von dyck group relations and that generated $GL(3,2)$. There are many other options.